# Select where id is not exist and it its value is 'a specific value'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables `StudentProgress` and `Songs`. I want to select all results where can join from `Songs` to `StudentProgress`, and all results which are not joined in two table and also `StudentID` from `StudentProgress` have a specific value..

This is my code for my first table which works well

```
 select 
     s.SongID,
     s.Title,
     s.Location,
     s.Rhythm 
 from  
     Songs s  
 join 
     StudentProgress f on s.SongID = f.SongID 
 where 
     f.StudentID = 17
```

Now I want to select from `StudentProgres` table the same which do not exist in the `Songs` table and also have a specific `StudentID` value.

I'm trying like this

```
select 
    s.SongID,
    s.Title,
    s.Location,
    s.Rhythm 
from 
    Songs s  
join 
    StudentProgress f on s.SongID = f.SongID 
where  
    f.StudentID is null 
    and f.studentid = 17
```

But I don't get any results.

See the screenshot here to understand

[image]

Comment: I need both of them. i mean where studentid=17 and not exist table Songs

Comment: You can't return items from `s` like `s.SongID` when you are looking for stuff that doesn't exist in Songs Table. Is your problem statement backwards?

Comment: Can you have a better data example for NOT EXIST in table Songs? The image of the data you provided has all NULLS on the 3rd row. And provide your expected result as well to understand your goal so we could help you much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `left Join` using the condition `f.studentid = 17` on the join condition you can find which song didnt have the student

```
select s.SongID,
       s.Title,
       s.Location,
       s.Rhythm 
  from Songs s  
  left join StudentProgress f 
    on s.SongID = f.SongID 
   and f.studentid = 17
 where f.StudentID is null
```

Comment: Thank you very much! this is what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

To find `Songs` which are not associated with Student ID 17,

```
select s.SongID,
       s.Title,
       s.Location,
       s.Rhythm 
  from Songs s  
  where s.SongID not in (select f.SongId from StudentProgress f where f.StudentID = 17)
```